# how to show form data object contents in angular2

Tags: angular

I tried values(),entries() property to display the form data objects in typescript.But it doesn't shown anything.I actually used it for getting the uploaded file contents and send  to the server.can anyone help me to solve this issue.when i give formData.values() it shows error.but when i give formData it shows an empty array.

```
 saveEditAgent(form: NgForm){
            console.log("==============================form========================================")
            console.log(form.value)
            let data;
            console.log("==============================form========================================")
            //this.spinner.showBlurSpinner();
            this.spinnerStatus=true;
            if (this.selectedFiles.length == 0){
                console.log('no profilepic choosen');
            }
            const formData: FormData = new FormData();
            const agentName = form.value.name;
            console.log('======agent Name======');
            console.log(agentName);
            if (this.selectedFiles.length != 0){
                console.log('====Yes ProfilePic===');
                const fileList: FileList = this.selectedFiles;
                const file: File          =   fileList[0];
                formData.append('name', agentName);
                formData.append('email', form.value.email);
                formData.append('displayName', form.value.displayname);
                formData.append('phoneNumber', form.value.phonenumber);
                formData.append('profilePicType', 'new');
                //formData.append('profilePic', file, file.name);
                formData.append('profilePic', this.file    , file.name);
                console.log(formData.values());
                data={
                    name:form.value.name,
                    displayName:form.value.displayname,
                    profilePicType:'new',
                    profilePic:formData
                    }
                console.log(data);  
            }
            else{
                formData.append('name', agentName);
                formData.append('email', form.value.email);
                formData.append('displayName', form.value.displayname);
                formData.append('phoneNumber', form.value.phonenumber);
                formData.append('profilePicType', 'old');
                console.log(formData.values());
                console.log('====No ProfilePic===');
                data={
                    name:form.value.name,
                    displayName:form.value.displayname,
                    profilePicType:'old'
                    }
            }
            let param={
                request:data
                }
            this.profileEditService.editOwner(param)
                .subscribe(
                    (response) => {
                        this.editAgentResponseStatus    =   response.status;
                        //this.spinner.hideSpinner();
                        this.spinnerStatus=false;
                        if(response.status==1){
                            const newPic = response.data.profilePic;
                            this.profilePic = response.data.profilePic;
                            this.toastrService.success('Profile updated successfully');
                            if (this.selectedFiles.length != 0){
                                // this.reloadParent.emit({src: this.itemPhoto  });
                               this.logout.ngOnInit();
                                console.log("lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllength")
                              //  this.spinner.showBlurSpinner();
                               // this.spinner.hideSpinner();
                                // this.router.navigateByUrl('/customer/agents', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
                                // this.router.navigate(["/customer/profile"]));
                               // document.getElementById()

                               //view child
                                this.logout.picChange();
                               console.log("**** pic change ****")
                               console.log(this.logout)
                               console.log("**** pic change ****")
                               //view child

                               //EventEmitter
                               this.onVoted.emit(this.profilePic);
                               //EventEmitter

                               //vote
                               this.vote(false);
                               //vote
                                this.disableBtn   =   true;
                                let imageRef:any  =   document.getElementById("icCustOwnerProfilePic");
                                imageRef.src  =      this.imageForHeader.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
                            }
                            let customerheaderName:any  =   document.getElementById("customerheaderName");
                            customerheaderName.textContent  =   agentName;
                            this.setFlagDefault();
                        }
                        else if (response.status == 2){
                           // this.showMessage('Please pass Name and Display Name');
                            this.toastrService.error('Please Provide Name and Display Name');
                            console.log(response.message);
                        }else if (response.status == 3){
                            this.logout.logOut();
                        }else if (response.status == 4){
                            this.showMessage(response.message);
                            this.toastrService.error(response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    (err) =>  {
                       // this.spinner.hideSpinner();
                       this.spinnerStatus=false;
                        console.log(err);
                        this.serverErrorFlag    =   true;
                       // this.router.navigate(['/customer/error']);
                    },
                );
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: saveEditAgent(form: FormGroup){..} ?